# Map from multiple sources DTOs to one target

Tags: java, mapstruct

Using MapStruct. Take as example:

```
class Dto {
    DtoA a;
    DtoB b;
}

class DtoA {
    Long id;
    //...
}

class DtoB {
    Long id;
    //...
}


class Entity {
    AB ab;
}
```

How do I map `DtoA` and `DtoB` to AB ?

I tried:

```
public abstract Entity toEntity(Dto dto);

@Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "a", target = "ab.a"),
            @Mapping(source = "b", target = "ab.b")
)}
public abstract AB toABEntity(DtoA a, DtoB b);
```

Altough code has been generated*, the method `toABEntity` is not invoked.

*Badly, as it sets first `a` but then to set `b` creates a new instance of `ab`, so `a` is lost.

Comment: Which version of MapStruct is this?

Comment: @Filip 1.2.0Final

Comment: What is `AB` in line `public abstract AB toABEntity(DtoA a, DtoB b);`?

Comment: @jannis I'm doing only one call: `toEntity`, as I want to map `Dto` to `Entity`. I've defined `toABEntity` hoping MapStruct will use it within `toEntity`.

Comment: Please describe exactly what do you want to map and where. It would be best if you give the desired input and output (an example `Dto` and example resulting `Entity`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand You want to map `Entity` to `Dto` and combine two fields `Dto.a` and `Dto.b` to a single field `Entity.ab`.

Normally when you try to do this like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "a.id", target = "ab.aId", qualifiedByName = "toAB"),
        @Mapping(source = "b.id", target = "ab.bId", qualifiedByName = "toAB"),
    })
    Entity toEntity(Dto dto);
}
```

The generated mapper overides `ab` instance for every `@Mapping` having a target property within `ab`. It's clearly a bug and there's a ticket for this at MapStructs GitHub: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1148

There's a workaround though:

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "dto", target = "ab", qualifiedByName = "toAB"),
    })
    Entity toEntity(Dto dto);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "aId", source = "a.id"),
        @Mapping(target = "bId", source = "b.id"),
    })
    AB toAB(Dto dto);
}
```

I assumed the `AB` class to be:

```
class AB {
    public Long aId;
    public Long bId;
}
```

Generated mapper code:

```
public class TestMapperImpl implements TestMapper {

    @Override
    public Entity toEntity(Dto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Entity entity = new Entity();

        entity.ab = toAB( dto );

        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public AB toAB(Dto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AB aB = new AB();

        Long id = dtoBId( dto );
        if ( id != null ) {
            aB.bId = id;
        }
        Long id1 = dtoAId( dto );
        if ( id1 != null ) {
            aB.aId = id1;
        }

        return aB;
    }

    private Long dtoBId(Dto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        DtoB b = dto.b;
        if ( b == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Long id = b.id;
        if ( id == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return id;
    }

    private Long dtoAId(Dto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        DtoA a = dto.a;
        if ( a == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Long id = a.id;
        if ( id == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that there's even an answer to this already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42987176/4494577